# MYSQL SELECT: check if rowdata exists

Tags: mysql, sql, select

In my SQL query i'm checking on different parameters. Nothing strange happens when there is data in each of the tables for the inserted tripcode. But when one table has no data in it I don't get any data at all. Even if the other tables have data. So I need to be able to check if the table has data in it and if it has, I need to select.

```
SELECT roadtrip_tblgeneral.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct roadtrip_tblhotels.hotel) as hotels,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct roadtrip_tbllocations.location) as locations,
GROUP_CONCAT(distinct roadtrip_tbltransports.transport) as transports
FROM roadtrip_tblgeneral
INNER JOIN roadtrip_tblhotels
ON roadtrip_tblgeneral.id = roadtrip_tblhotels.tripid
INNER JOIN roadtrip_tbllocations
ON roadtrip_tblgeneral.id = roadtrip_tbllocations.tripid
INNER JOIN roadtrip_tbltransports
ON roadtrip_tblgeneral.id = roadtrip_tbltransports.tripid
WHERE roadtrip_tblgeneral.tripcode = :tripcode
GROUP BY roadtrip_tblgeneral.id
```

Only the tables with the GROUP_CONCAT in front need the check. I already tried with the keyword EXISTS in front of it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The INNER JOIN keyword returns rows when there is at least one match in both tables.  You can't have a match if there is no data, perhaps you want to use a LEFT JOIN or a FULL JOIN.

Comment: Thanks, LEFT JOIN did the job. If there is no data in a specific result it just returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Left join will be use as it returns all the data from the table at left, even if there is no matching rows in right table